# Removing specific pattern from string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I have a string such as

> ' This is a nice string with some size in inches at the end 25.6" '

Number before the double quotes might be float or integer of any length. I want to remove everything between a space and double quote sign. Right now I am trying to do something with .find() functions to get the index of double quote sign and the last space and then to remove each symbol between those indexes. Is there any smarter way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using `re.sub` here:

```
input = ' This is a nice string with some size in inches at the end 25.6" '
output = re.sub(r'\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)"\s*$', '', input)
print(output)

This is a nice string with some size in inches at the end
```

The regex pattern `\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)"\s*$` says to:

```
\s+       match one or more spaces
\d+       match one or more digits, followed by
(?:\.\d+) an optional decimal component
"         inches unit sign
\s*       possible trailing whitespace, until
$         the end of the string
```